# Bootstrap modal closes on click anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a modal:

```
<script>
    $('#moment-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
        var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
        // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
        // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
    })
</script>
```

but when it opens it closes no matter where I click. I have added a few input fields, and when I click on field to type something it closes.

I've tried in HTML with:

```
data-backdrop="true"
data-backdrop="static"
```

and

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

So both JS and HTML options, and it is still doing the same.

Comment: Who were you Norgul? What did you see? | https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you remember how you have resolved the issue (if you ever have resolved)?